# How to disallow installation of modules using npm if license type is not whitelist

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

We would like to maintain a list of license types we allow to be used in the project. How can `npm install packagename` command be blocked/errored if license type of the `packagaename` is not in the whitelist.

I understand there are packages like license-checker that can summarize the modules used in the project, however, that is after something has been installed. I'd just like not to install a package that doesn't match the allowed license types.

Comment: AFAIK, npm does not provide a built-in feature to prevent the installation of a package whose license is not  whitelisted. You may want to consider implementing the license check as part of your projects test process. E.g. [Here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/127f524337f92dd72d36e71e646c91c9715ad444/Makefile.js#L951) you can see that the `eslint` tool utilizes [npm-license](https://github.com/AceMetrix/npm-license) plus custom code for verification. They simply fail the test if/when an impermissible license is found.